# End to End Ad campaigns Tracking Issue: Branch.io link attribution not working

Tags: branch.io

We are running Ads on Landing Pages for Users to Download our App by Clicking on a Download Button placed there.

Now, the problem we are facing is that the Branch links placed in Ads are tracking clicks and for Google Ads, they are even tracking impressions, but all the Installs, Registrations, Add cash and other in App events are being sent in the unpopulated data.

How do we solve this and be able to track every campaign from Clicks to in App activities like Purchase.

Below are the ways we ran branch links in Ads:

1. In Google Ads, we added these links to the Tracking Template.
2. In Meta Ads, we ran the ad links made for facebook in the destination url of the Ads.

We wanted to track every campaign from Clicks to in App activities like Purchase and be able to attribute these events to specific ads and campaigns on various Ad platforms like Meta Ads and Google Ads.